# Chrome webview stopped loading HTML

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, nativescript, android-webview

We have an app. built using Angular and NativeScript.
The app loads a webview with HTML page.
It used to work until today and stopped in version 92 of chrome.
We load the webview using:
this.webViewInterface = new WebViewInterface(this.epubWebView, htmlUrl);

htmlUrl points to a HTML file in app documents directory.

Does someone have any idea why it stopped loading local HTML.

Comment: It seems like a bug in Android WebView that was recently updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was a bug in Android WebView.
Chrome WebView was updated and now it works.